# Melt multiple columns pandas dataframe based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4],
    'Gender': ['F','F','M','M'],
    'Language': ['EN', 'ES', 'EN', 'EN'],
    'Year 1': [2020,2020,2020,2020],
    'Score 1': [93,97,83,86],
    'Year 2': [2020,2020,None,2018],
    'Score 2': [85,95,None,55],
    'Year 3': [2020,2018,None,None],
    'Score 3': [87,86,None,None]
    }
)
```

| ID | Gender | Language | Year 1 | Score 1 | Year 2 | Score 2 | Year 3 | Score 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | EN | 2020 | 93 | 2020 | 85 | 2020 | 87 |
| 2 | F | ES | 2020 | 97 | 2020 | 95 | 2018 | 86 |
| 3 | M | EN | 2020 | 83 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | M | EN | 2020 | 86 | 2018 | 55 |  |  |

And I would like to melt based on the year and the corresponding scores, for example if any year equals 2020 then the following would be generated:

| ID | Gender | Language | Year | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | EN | 2020 | 93 |
| 1 | F | EN | 2020 | 85 |
| 1 | F | EN | 2020 | 87 |
| 2 | F | ES | 2020 | 97 |
| 2 | F | ES | 2020 | 95 |
| 3 | M | EN | 2020 | 83 |
| 4 | M | EN | 2020 | 86 |

I have tried using `pd.melt` but am having trouble filtering by the year across the columns and keeping the corresponding entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i understand, you may try:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(dataframe,['Year','Score'],['ID','Gender','Language'],'v',' ')
                                               .dropna().droplevel(-1).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

   ID Gender Language    Year  Score
0   1      F       EN  2020.0   93.0
1   1      F       EN  2020.0   85.0
2   1      F       EN  2020.0   87.0
3   2      F       ES  2020.0   97.0
4   2      F       ES  2020.0   95.0
5   2      F       ES  2018.0   86.0
6   3      M       EN  2020.0   83.0
7   4      M       EN  2020.0   86.0
8   4      M       EN  2018.0   55.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long_df = (pd.wide_to_long(dataframe, stubnames=["Year","Score"],i="ID", j="Repetition",
                           sep = " ").reset_index())
df_2020 = (long_df[long_df["Year"] == 2020].drop("Repetition",
                                                 axis=1).sort_values("ID").reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(df_2020)

   ID Gender Language    Year  Score
0   1      F       EN  2020.0   93.0
1   1      F       EN  2020.0   85.0
2   1      F       EN  2020.0   87.0
3   2      F       ES  2020.0   97.0
4   2      F       ES  2020.0   95.0
5   3      M       EN  2020.0   83.0
6   4      M       EN  2020.0   86.0
```